# Cloud Firestore on Datastore Mode Performance Numbers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Does anyone here have experience dealing with high volume of writes/reads for cloud firestore on datastore mode ?

We are expecting a maximum of a million users accessing the datastore for a day. The load could be distributed over the day, and expecting a maximum of 500 concurrent client requests.

The writes could be as fast as possible, and we could be writing a maximum of 100M records daily (as a batch). The data could be read from BigQuery and will be written to the datastore on a daily basis.

EDIT : We could be dealing with max of 100GB of data only

Comment: Datastore is scaled automatically, so I suppose it will handle this amount of users. I think you should consider as well total capacity.  If I remember rightly, if total capacity of the database is measured in PB Google is recommending BigTable or Spanner. Do you know how much total capacity you need?

Comment: @vittoh, We could be dealing in GBs only, I am looking for the read performance of datstore

Comment: Theoretically Datastore should fit your purposes. If are searching for real low-latency Google is recommending BigTable, however from provided description Datastore should be enough.